# Symfony Form passing variable options from Collection to FormType

Tags: php, forms, symfony-forms, symfony

i have a collection type:

```
->add('tipi', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => TipiType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
                'entry_options' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => false,
                )
            ))
```

Extend this formtype:

```
->add('tipi', EntityType::class, array(
      'label' => 'Tipo',
      'class' => 'AppBundle:Tipi',
      'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
      'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
          return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                    ->innerJoin('t.requests', 'r')
          ;
      },
  ));
```

In the first form type i have an options sended from controller in this way:

```
$idRequest = $request->get('id');
$form = $this->createForm(RequestsType::class, $requests, array(
    'id_request' => $idRequest
));
```

In the first I can use it, but in the child FormType not. I would passing this variable in the collection type. How can I do that?

```
$form = $this->createForm(new YourForm($options), $class);
```

Comment: In the collection type you could use the `$options['id_request']` for pass to the child

Comment: In the first form work but in the second not.. @Matteo

Comment: you should be able to pass it in the options array like `'entry_type' => TipiType::class, 'id_request' => $options['id_request']`